# I want to embed Twitter or something that is connected to Twitter through API in an IFRAME

Tags: iframe, twitter

Does anyone have a solution for embedding twitter or all of its functionality into an iframe...

Basically what I want is to embed Twitter within my webapp so my clients can use it as a marketing tool while also using my application.  If someone has an API solution completed that I can embed through an iframe I am willing to look at it for purchase.

If you know of a solution let me know...

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Why not use the Twitter API? http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation. I did for my project, in java and it works like a charm.

Comment: I am trying to embed all the functionality of twitter within my app through an iframe.  If someone has an API sollution completed that i can embed through an IFrame i am willing to look at it for purchase

Comment: If you want ALL of twitter in an IFrame, then you're stuck with their login "stuff".

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://twitter.com/someonespage" width="800" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

If you want more control than this, you'll probably need to use the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) to build your own solution.

[Here's a](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202214722/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021710-1.aspx) great blog on integrating the Twitter API directly into your web App.

Comment: BUt i want my user to be able to log in and post etc...
When you go to twitter and log in it takes over the whole frame...

Comment: That's Twitter's doing. They probably don't want you doing this. Don't like it? Make a Twitter clone.

Comment: I edited my answer above.  You should check out the Twitter API. http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

Comment: I am reviewing the API but if someone knows a good sollid sollution already done i am looking for suggestions

Comment: There are tons of other solutions out there that are already doing what you're doing.  If you want in in your own web page, then you need to build it all yourself.  Check out http://CoTweet.Com for some ideas on the robustness of the API.

Comment: Twitter appears to be rejecting my call when using an IFrame. I wonder if they have something blocking IFrame requests now.

Answer (score -5):

```
<iframe src="http://m.dabr.co.uk" width="800" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: So what? I can't copy&paste the common text used in over 9000 websites? Look at src attribute ;)

Comment: you can't log into this when embedded in a frame

Comment: I will edit this this works in IE6 on xp but not on IE8 Windows 7

Comment: [IE?? Why you are using it?] - it's not about HIM using it... it's about his USERS using it.  IE8 has all kinds of security features that basically KILL iFrames.  Unfortunately it's DEVELOPERS who need to worry about making their app cross browser compatible.  Not doing so would be a mistake.  Forcing users to NOT use IE is a mistake.